# How to solve task with regex

Tags: python, regex

Task:
The input is a string consisting of characters A, B, C.

Find the maximal number of "A*A" or "C*C" sub-strings, that are consecutive.

Where the * sign stands for any possible character.

Take into account overlaps.

---

INPUT: https://kompege.ru/files/sJDwcyfWx.txt

OUTPUT: 21

LANGUAGE: PYTHON

Solution without RegEX (Correct):

```
with open("./data/24_4546.txt") as f:
    s = f.readline().replace('\n', '')

c = m = 0
for j in range(3):
    for i in range(j, len(s) - 2, 3):
        if s[i] + s[i + 2] == "AA" or s[i] + s[i + 2] == "CC":
            c += 1
        else:
            m = max(m, c)
            c = 0

m = max(m, c)
print(m)
```

---

My attempts with regex (not work):

```
import re
with open("./data/24_4546.txt") as f:
    s = f.readline().replace('\n', '')

print(len(max(re.sub(r"[^*]", " ", re.sub(r"(?=A[A-C]A)|(?=C[A-C]C)", "*", s)).split(), key=len)))
```

Comment: Your example code is finding strings that end in `A.A|C.C` which is different than `A*A|C*C`

Comment: Regex is not meant and can't find *longest* strings of chars. You must evaluate the match length once the matches are obtained.

Comment: [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) has a flag for overlapping. You could spare the lookahead and use something like [`re.findall(r'(?:A.A|C.C)+', s, overlapped=True)])`](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3@YrZJcHSLroTikzzC@7ERaCpBvJi0koF/z0WWkUXwzncO8Ok53SPoS3F@hRpAjI3s4DOqzCWoQOuUPX74Ebc2O@52g1/iJ/tXn2v/1vOWCIbJuH1Ii7OBOEljJHAgw3r93q0YdDOCeLidMQaX6pW8sAryBXEhyGnUzJDd6bZyKtsmlaW8gY) for the regex part.

Comment: @bobblebubble , i can't use extended libs for solve this task, but thanks for idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *trick* is to use capturing group in lookahead assertion `(?=...)`:

```py
import re

with open("./data/24_4546.txt") as f:
    s = f.read().strip()

out = max(len(m) // 3  for m, *_ in re.findall(r'(?=((?:([AC]).\2)+))[AC]', s))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
21
```